# Cannot add C file to Yocto Layer using bitbake

Tags: multithreading, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have a C file binary to add as custom layer in the yocto and run in qemu. I have created layer using `bitbake-layers create-layer meta-custLayer` and added using `bitbake-layers add-layer meta-custLayer`. The file tree of meta-custLayer is as:
[image: file tree]

The **example_0.1.bb** file has the following:

```
SUMMARY = "bitbake-layers recipe"
DESCRIPTION = "Recipe created by bitbake-layers"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COREBASE}/meta/files/common-licenses/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://threading.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"
TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"

do_compile(){
    $(CC) threading.c -o threads -lpthreads
}


do_install(){
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 threads
${D}${bindir}s
}
```

When the command `bitbake example` is executed, this is the output:

```
ERROR: example-0.1-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/sajil/edm_yocto/sources/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/example/0.1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.1806553' failed with exit code 127:
/home/sajil/edm_yocto/sources/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/example/0.1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.1806553: 99: CC: not found
/home/sajil/edm_yocto/sources/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/example/0.1-r0/temp/run.do_compile.1806553: 99: threading.c: not found
WARNING: exit code 127 from a shell command.
```

when `bitbake core-image-minimal` is executed, terminal shows that *threads* is unbuildable and runs into error:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'threads' (but /home/sajil/edm_yocto/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'threads' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['threads']
ERROR: Required build target 'core-image-minimal' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['core-image-minimal', 'threads']
```

I checked the path of the custom layer directory, being correct. I am clueless about the errors I am confronting.

For now my task is to run the C-file (adding it as a layer) on QEMU. I am unable to build the image for the same.

I would appreciate some help and insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple issues on your recipe:

- Your `do_compile` command does not indicate where to find your .c file
- You should use `${CC}` instead of `$(CC)`
- `lpthread` does not end with and `s`

```
do_compile() {
    ${CC} ${S}/threading.c -o ${S}/threads -lpthread
}
```

- Your `do_install` does not provide the correct path to your binary:

```
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/threads ${D}${bindir}
}
```

- At the end you should populate the packages:

```
FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}"
```

---

**Edit about `threads` unbuildable:**

`threads` is unbuildable because the recipe does not mention that the package is `threads`.

Here you have some options:

- Rename your recipe to `threads_0.1.bb` (I recommend you to use a less generic name)
- use the `PACKAGES` variable in your recipe. You will need to modify the `FILES_*` variable too. (a bit complicated if you are new to Yocto)
- Use the current recipe name, and change the `IMAGE_INSTALL += "threads"` to `IMAGE_INSTALL += "example"`

Comment: Thanks for your input! I did the changes you mentioned and compiled. ```bitbake example``` did not show any errors however, ```bitbake core-image-minimal``` gave error same as before i.e *threads* is unbuildable. What could I be still doing wrong ?

Comment: @Sajil I updated my answer, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! I implemented all your corrections and programmatically i got it right. However, later i found that the .conf file which is was editing for ```IMAGE_INSTALL``` was not the one i was supposed to change. There are 3 build folders and i edit the wrong one ! Thanks a lot !